# how to deploy apachel cxf to websphere application server

Tags: cxf, websphere-8

i created a sample apache cxf SOAP webservices, following the tutorial [here](http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident.html)

i'm able to run on tomcat 9 via eclipse neon and access it at http://localhost:8080/camel-example-reportincident/webservices/incident?wsdl.

i installed and started it on websphere, but i can't access it on the same url. i also tried all other ports listed in default host alias.

my maven libraries:
[image]

here is my wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> <wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"    xmlns:tns="http://reportincident.example.camel.apache.org" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"    targetNamespace="http://reportincident.example.camel.apache.org">

    <!-- Type definitions for input- and output parameters for webservice
-->     <wsdl:types>        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://reportincident.example.camel.apache.org">            <xs:element name="inputReportIncident">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="incidentId" />
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="incidentDate" />
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="givenName" />
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="familyName" />
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="summary" />
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="details" />
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="email" />
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="phone" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>           </xs:element>           <xs:element name="outputReportIncident">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="code" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>           </xs:element>       </xs:schema>    </wsdl:types>

    <!-- Message definitions for input and output -->   <wsdl:message name="inputReportIncident">       <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:inputReportIncident" />   </wsdl:message>     <wsdl:message name="outputReportIncident">      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:outputReportIncident" />  </wsdl:message>

    <!-- Port (interface) definitions -->   <wsdl:portType name="ReportIncidentEndpoint">       <wsdl:operation name="ReportIncident">          <wsdl:input message="tns:inputReportIncident" />            <wsdl:output message="tns:outputReportIncident" />      </wsdl:operation>   </wsdl:portType>

    <!-- Port bindings to transports and encoding - HTTP, document literal encoding         is used -->     <wsdl:binding name="ReportIncidentBinding" type="tns:ReportIncidentEndpoint">       <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />       <wsdl:operation name="ReportIncident">          <soap:operation
                soapAction="http://reportincident.example.camel.apache.org/ReportIncident"
                style="document" />             <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal" />          </wsdl:input>           <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal" />          </wsdl:output>      </wsdl:operation>   </wsdl:binding>

    <!-- Service definition -->     <wsdl:service name="ReportIncidentService">         <wsdl:port name="ReportIncidentPort" binding="tns:ReportIncidentBinding">           <soap:address location="http://reportincident.example.camel.apache.org" />      </wsdl:port>    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

here is my ibm-web-bnd.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">   <virtual-host name="default_host"/> </web-bnd>
```

here is my cxf-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <!-- implementation of the webservice -->
    <bean id="reportIncidentEndpoint"
        class="org.apache.camel.example.reportincident.impl.ReportIncidentEndpointImpl" />

    <!-- export the webservice using jaxws -->
    <jaxws:endpoint id="reportIncident" implementor="#reportIncidentEndpoint"
        address="/incident" wsdlLocation="/WEB-INF/wsdl/report_incident.wsdl"
        endpointName="s:ReportIncidentPort" serviceName="s:ReportIncidentService"
        xmlns:s="http://reportincident.example.camel.apache.org" />

</beans>
```

here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- the listener that kick-starts Spring -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- CXF servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- all our webservices are mapped under this URI pattern -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- location of spring xml files -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:cxf-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

====================

## Update

strangely, the last update for SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log were two days ago. i found some logs in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc
logs:

```
FFDC Exception:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated ProbeId:1341 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl@bdd2e142
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:985)
.....


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1032)


Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/apache/camel/component/cxf/transport/CamelTransportFactory, offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:273)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:74)


com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_24638c34_17.05.05_01.11.23.0597458986526819616127.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstance.init 181

    com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module Archetype Created Web Application has been bound to default_host[*:9080,*:80,*:9443,*:5060,*:5061,*:443].

WSVR0221I: Application started: camel-example-reportincident_war

WSVR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=camel-example-reportincident_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=camel-example-reportincident_war started.
```

Comment: You'll need to check your WebSphere server logs (particularly SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log) to see if there are errors there that might be causing the application to fail to start.  Also, if you haven't done so already, make sure you're following the steps in the docs on third-party web services, as that requires some extra configuration: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html

Comment: Please provide the server logs. Have you checked the CXF guide http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-ForWebSphere6.1.0.29+,V7andV8

Comment: updated with logs

Comment: added a screenshot of my maven libraries

Answer (score 0):

An UnsupportedClassVersionError means that the class (in this case, CamelTransportFactory) was compiled against a higher level of Java than the JVM that you're running on.  If you have a version of WebSphere that supports higher Java spec levels, you'll need to pick up a higher-level JDK; if not, then you'll need a version of the Camel package that supports Java 6.

Comment: hi, tks. i recompiled with 1.6 jdk and now it's a different error. " javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/DESKTOP-8TUH2K0Node01Cell/camel-example-reportincident_war.ear/camel-example-reportincident.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar location rather than from a product class loader.". Is this related to setting load parent last?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I don't know that that's explicitly an error, though, just an informational message.

Comment: Ok I will check. But how do I know the end point? I set contextRoot on websphere as test. On tomcat, my URL is http://localhost:8080/camel-example-reportincident/webservice/incident?wsdl. I tried http://localhost:8080/test/camel-example-reportincident/webservice/incident?wsdl but it throws a 404